# Laravel Auth fail with duplicated user's email

Tags: laravel, authentication

My application needs to store the same user many times. That's because when a user is removed, I make a logical exclusion, just changing a status field in the user table. However, if I have two users with the same email, Laravel Auth fails. How do I can solve this problem? How Can I customize auth to consider this status field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LoginController you can override credentials method which exists in AuthenticatesUsers trait

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    // return ['email' => .., 'password' => .., 'status' => 1];

    return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Abdulrahman. I was almost there. That's the best solution for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can add custom condition like:

```
if ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1]) ) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vikash, but I'm using Laravel Auth, created with php artisan make: auth... login() method is called when there is a login post request. How Can I make that changes? Inside a trait AuthenticatesUsers??? Inside a LoginController? I'm sorry.. I'm a beginner.. I yet couldn't understand Auth details very well...

Comment: You can go to Auth/LoginController and make these changes

Comment: Not an issue, everyone was biginner at one stage :) Let me know if it helps.